# Adding an EventListener after page is loaded through a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, addeventlistener

**EDIT:**

Turns out the issue was that you can't use the scroll event if the element isn't overflowing. Use 'wheel' event instead.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

Is there a way for me to add an EventListener after the site is loaded though a function. I have an svg-animation that runs, and I don't want the EventListener to be activated before the animation is done, which I would assume should look something like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.board').addClass('active');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.svg-container').addClass('activate');           
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            doSomething();
        });

    }, 10000);

});

function doSomething() {
    alert('test');          
}
```

But nothing happens – no errors are thrown in the log either. Is there a way to add an eventlistener on the fly?

Comment: working fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/ML930MUlu7oQzItzabqQ?p=preview whats the exact issue ?

Comment: @Deep I see the problem is that the screen wasn't overflowing, so I was looking for the 'wheel'-event instead

Comment: okays :) i did add style to overflow the screen in my example above